# Extract URL parameters and values in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

We want to extract parameters and values from a given URL like

```
http://www.exemple.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3#def
```

Using xml2::url_parse we were able to Parse a url into its component pieces. However we still want to devide the query into elements using gsub matching regular expression:

```
([^?&=#]+)=([^&#]*)
```

Desired output

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `urltools` package to parse URLs.

```
> u <- "http://www.exemple.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3#def"
> strsplit(urltools::parameters(u), "&")[[1L]]
[1] "a=1" "b=2" "c=3"
> urltools::param_get(u, "b")
  b
1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
library(stringr)
matrix(str_extract_all(str1, "[a-z](?=\\=)|(?<=\\=)\\d+")[[1]], ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

Or if we need the `=` also

```
 str_extract_all(str1, "[a-z]=\\d+")[[1]]
 #[1] "a=1" "b=2" "c=3"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "http://www.exemple.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3#def"
```