# Extracting parameter from URL in R

Tags: r, regex, substring, gsub

I'd like to remove a 'destinationId' parameter from a batch of URLs.

If i have a URL like this:

https://urlaub.xxx.de/lastminute/europa/zypern-griechenland/?destinationId=45&semcid=de.ub

How would i extract the 45? (destinationId=45)

I attempted to use something like this which i cant get to work:

```
destinationIdParameter <- sub("[^0-9].*","",sub("*?\\destinationId=","",url))
```

Comment: Remove from url or extract from url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match the bundle id for android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628728/how-to-match-the-bundle-id-for-android-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract URL parameters and values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811595/extract-url-parameters-and-values-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `stringr` you can get it like this:

```
> library(stringr)
> address <- "https://urlaub.xxx.de/lastminute/europa/zypern-griechenland/?destinationId=45&semcid=de.ub"
> str_match(address, "destinationId=(.*?)&")[,2]
[1] "45"
```

If (like me) you're not comfortable with regular expressions, use the `qdapRegex` package:

```
> library(qdapRegex)
> address <- "https://urlaub.xxx.de/lastminute/europa/zypern-griechenland/?destinationId=45&semcid=de.ub"
> ex_between(address, "destinationId=", "&")
[[1]]
[1] "45"
```

Comment: Thanks! I really like the qdapRegex approach as regular expressions are confusing. It's not as quick to compute as gsub solution tho :(

Answer (score 1):

With base R you can extract the number in few ways. If you are certain there is always only one number in this kind of urls, you can just erase everything which is not a number by:

```
> url <- "https://urlaub.xxx.de/lastminute/europa/zypern-griechenland/?destinationId=45&semcid=de.ub"
> gsub("[^0-9]", "", url)
[1] "45"
```

Or if you want to be more safe and want the particular number which comes after "destinationId=" not any other, then you would do something like this:

```
destId <- regmatches(url, gregexpr("destinationId=\\d+", url)) 
gsub("[^0-9]", "", destId)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to extract the `destinationId` value from the url, then you could do:

```
gsub(".+destinationId=(\\d+).+", "\\1", url)
```

- Here `\\1` refers to what is within `()`.
- `.+` matches any character
  sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is [`parameters()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46703354/5783745)

```
library(urltools)
example_url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Halfaker?debug=true"
parameters(example_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

With base `R`, we can do:

```
url <- "https://urlaub.xxx.de/lastminute/europa/zypern-griechenland/?destinationId=45&semcid=de.ub"

extract <- function(url) {
  pattern <- "destinationId=\\K\\d+"
  (id <- regmatches(url, regexpr(pattern, url, perl = TRUE)))
}

print(extract(url))
```

---

Alternatively (no `perl = TRUE`):

```
vanilla_extract <- function(url) {
  pattern <- "destinationId=([^&]+)"
  (regmatches(url, regexec(pattern, url))[[1]][2])
}
```

Both yield

```
[1] "45"
```